# resize label width according to window size using extjs

Tags: extjs6

I am using extjs 6.0.2. I want to adjust label width according to the size of the window. how can I do that please help. I have tried this following code but no use.

```
{
            xtype : 'label',
            itemId: 'recordNumberShowItem',
            style: 'color: #707070; font-family: VegurMedium,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;',
//          text: Ext.String.format(me.displayRecordNumberMsg, 0, 0, 0, me.recordName),
            scope: me,
            listeners : {
                show : function ( label , eOpts ){
//                  width: (window.outerWidth < 1350) ? 70 : 140,
                            if(window.outerWidth < 1350){
                                label.setWidth(70);
                            }
                            else{
                                label.setWidth(null);
                            }
                } 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.create({
            xtype:'window',
            width:200,
            height:200,
            resizable:true,
            items:[
                {
                    xtype:'label',
                    width:'100%',
                    style:'    word-wrap: break-word;',
                    text:'dawbnduiawbndawbduibdwuiabduiw'
                }]
        }).show();
```

here is a fiddle for you: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1lv3